# I would like to run an async method synchronously when the async function causes a dialog to show on the UI?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

In my Xamarin.Forms application, I have some code that looks like this

```
private async void OnEntryLosesFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vm = (MainPageViewModel)BindingContext;
    if (vm == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!IsAnyNavButtonPressedOnUWP())
    {
        // CheckAndSaveData() causes dialogs to show on the UI.
        // I need to ensure that CheckAndSaveData() completes its execution and control is not given to another function while it is running.
        var _saveSuccessfulInUnfocus = await vm.CheckAndSaveData();
        if (_saveSuccessfulInUnfocus)
        {
            if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
            {
                if (_completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP)
                {
                    var navAction = vm.GetNavigationCommand();
                    navAction?.Invoke();
                    _completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP = false;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                vm._stopwatchForTap.Restart();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            vm._stopwatchForTap.Restart();
        }
    }    
}
```

The method above is an `EventHandler` for the unfocus event for one of my entries. However due to the way Xamarin works when a button is clicked the Unfocused event is triggered before the Command attached is executed.

I need to ensure that the function `vm.CheckAndSaveData()` finishes executing before the command attached to this button hence why I need to run it synchronously.

I have tried multiple things but they all result in deadlocks.

Some of the solutions I have tried are in this question: [How would I run an async Task<T> method synchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095183/how-would-i-run-an-async-taskt-method-synchronously)

THEY ALL RESULT IN DEADLOCKS. There has to be some way I can run my function synchronously or at least force the function `CheckAndSaveData` to finish before anything else.

Comment: Can CheckAndSaveData be made sync?

Comment: nope it has async methods inside so it cannot be made sync

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily a duplicate, although the title suggests it is. But to address the issue, I can think of two solutions: 1. In `CheckAndSaveData()`, use `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on all the uses of `await`, as long as it's not changing the UI after that line. Then use `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in your unfocus event. Or 2. Use [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) in your unfocus event and your command event to make the command event wait until the unfocus event is complete.

Comment: I can edit `CheckAndSaveData()`. I can share the contents of that function here if needed. That function does in fact show a dialog on my app's UI and I believe that may be whats causing the issue. I have tried using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` as well as using await `Device.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync()` but that didn't work. I am not very well versed with Async code and I am not sure how I would use the SemaphoreSlim in my case. Are you able to expand on this a little bit?

Comment: in uwp, you can't run an async method in sync mode, GetAwaiter().GetResult() is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using info form the answers provided as well as help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122936/write-an-async-method-that-will-await-a-bool)

Here's how I did it.

```
private async void OnEntryLosesFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vm = (MainPageViewModel)BindingContext;
    if (vm == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    // A public variable in my view model which is initially set to null.
    vm.UnfocusTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var saveSuccessful = await vm.CheckAndSaveData();
    vm.UnfocusTaskCompletionSource.SetResult(saveSuccessful);

    if (saveSuccessful && Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP &&
        _completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP)
    {
        var navAction = vm.GetNavigationCommand();
        navAction?.Invoke();
        _completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP = false;
    }
    /*Set this back to null. (This is very important for my use case.). Just in case this function executes completely before the Button click command executes for whatever reason */
    vm.UnfocusTaskCompletionSource = null;
}
```

In the function for my `Command` attached to the button I have something like below

```
private async void OnButtonTap(ArrorDirection direction)
{
    bool preventMove = false;

    if (UnfocusTaskCompletionSource != null)
    {
        /*Wait for `CheckAndSaveData() from `OnEntryLoosesFocus()` to complete and get the return value. */
        await UnfocusTaskCompletionSource.Task;
        var dataCheckAndSaveSuccessful = UnfocusTaskCompletionSource.Task.Result;
        preventMove = !dataCheckAndSaveSuccessful;
    }

    // Do stuff in function:
    if (preventMove){
        DoMove()
    }


    UnfocusTaskCompletionSource = null;
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Congratulations, you have found one of the corner cases where *there is no solution*. There are [hacks for sync-over-async that work in some cases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), but no solution will work here.

Here's why no known solutions will work:

- You can't directly block because `CheckAndSaveData` needs to run a UI loop.
- You can't block on a thread pool thread because `CheckAndSaveData` interacts with the UI.
- You can't use a replacement single-threaded `SynchronizationContext` (as in the incorrectly linked duplicate), because `CheckAndSaveData` needs to pump Win32 messages.
- You can't even use a nested UI loop (Dispatcher Frame in this case), because pumping those same Win32 messages will cause your command to be executed.

Put more simply:

- `CheckAndSaveData` must pump messages to show a UI.
- `CheckAndSaveData` cannot pump messages to prevent the command from executing.

So, there is no solution here.

Instead, you'll need to modify your command so that it waits for `CheckAndSaveData` somehow, either using a synchronization primitive or by just calling `CheckAndSaveData` directly from the command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ended up using a solution that involved a `TaskCompletionSource` this question was helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122936/write-an-async-method-that-will-await-a-bool

Answer (score 1):

An option is to use [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) in your unfocus event and your command event to make the command event wait until the unfocus event is complete.

When a part of your code enters the semaphore (using [`Wait`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.wait) or [`WaitAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync)), it will block other parts of your code that try to enter the semaphore until the semaphore is released.

Here's an example of what that could look like:

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1,1);

private async void OnEntryLosesFocus(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var vm = (MainPageViewModel)BindingContext;
    if (vm == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (!IsAnyNavButtonPressedOnUWP())
    {
        try {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            
            // CheckAndSaveData() causes dialogs to show on the UI.
            // I need to ensure that CheckAndSaveData() completes its execution and control is not given to another function while it is running.
            _saveSuccessfulInUnfocus = await vm.CheckAndSaveData();
            if (_saveSuccessfulInUnfocus)
            {
                if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP)
                {
                    if (_completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP)
                    {
                        var navAction = vm.GetNavigationCommand();
                        navAction?.Invoke();
                        _completedTriggeredForEntryOnUWP = false;
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    vm._stopwatchForTap.Restart();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                vm._stopwatchForTap.Restart();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
        }
    }    
}

private async void OnCommand(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
        // Execution will wait here until Release() is called in OnEntryLosesFocus
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        
        // do stuff
    }
    finally
    {
        _semaphore.Release();
    }
}
```

The `try`/`finally` blocks are optional, but it helps make absolutely sure that the semaphore is released even if an unhandled exception happens.

Comment: This was helpful in pointing me in the right direction. I ended up using a `TaskCompletionSource` inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122936/write-an-async-method-that-will-await-a-bool.